# Blinking Tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am using a tooltip on a listbox and although it works it keeps flickering/blinking any idea's how to fix this?
The only thing i could think of was turning on double buffering but that didn't work.

this is the function i use;

```
private void onMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBox)
    {
        Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        int hoverIndex = LSB_OfflineVars.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (hoverIndex >= 0 && hoverIndex < LSB_OfflineVars.Items.Count)
        {
            tt.SetToolTip(LSB_OfflineVars, LSB_OfflineVars.Items[hoverIndex].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Comment: The relevant code is missing so we can't really help, just guess. What is `LSB_OfflineVars`? What is the code for `SetToolTip` method?

Comment: Why are you 'helping' the tt provider?

Comment: @shadow - it's actually quite complete and comprehensible.

Comment: It's flickering because your code is in the MouseMove event, which fires whenever the mouse is moved at all, so you keep re-displaying the tooltip.

Comment: @Henk yeah, sorry didn't figure he was using the [ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [onMouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousehover.aspx) instead should resolve the issue as it will not be triggered as often but still provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve this by just adding
            tt.toolTip.Hide(dataGridCurrAlarms); 
            tt.toolTip.RemoveAll();
at the beginning of the method

Answer (score 0):

How about if you set the [`ShowAlways`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.showalways.aspx) property to true.